# Phonegap - Does it compile the webpages or simply wrap them

Tags: css, cordova

I'm new to Cordova and Phonegap. I've encountered a problem where some CSS3 cannot be displayed properly on my (old) Android.

So I wonder if Phonegap compiles the webpages into code (perhaps Java) or just simply wraps it and uses a native browser to open it.

I ask this is just simply out curiosity and wonder if I can implement ways in other forms to help it render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap just uses a WebView (Which is essentailly a browser) control where it displays your webpages. Now each phone uses a different WebView control, and also this control varies among different versions of android. So if some parts of your page are not displayed correctly inside the phone's web browser, they won't show up correctly inside a phonegap app.

**UPDATE**:

A solution to this problem might be [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2460324/mobile-java/apache-cordova-lets-developers-create-android-apps-from-third-party-webviews.html):

> "[Third-party WebViews] are platform-independent so that we no longer
>   have to deal with issues between Android versions," said Bowser, who
>   spoke Thursday at OSCON in Portland, Ore. An API will be provided so
>   that these WebViews work like plug-ins, and Bowser mentioned it will
>   support the recent Android OSes, such as KitKat, Jelly Bean, and
>   Gingerbread.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the additional information you've gathered :D